# How do I make the sidebar on page, extend as the content of the page? Picture as below:

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been using a sidebar with transparent background and left border(Orange colour) to appear on all my pages. But it has a min-height: 100vh. It only appears on half of the page. I want the border to appear as far as the content of the page.

[image]

Code:`

```
 #secondary {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 0;
            clear: none;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 0 -97.5%;
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 122px;
}`
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include the code for the page so that the problem can be explored properly?

Comment: @Danny it is a wordpress twenty-fourteen theme. I am using css to style this element.

Comment: Okay, can you include the HTML and CSS that is causing your problem in your question?

Comment: Include your html and css codes, or add links to the page, where it's happening.

Comment: @Danny please see the code attached. I would appreciate for any advise.

Comment: @ChandniVishen I would need enough of the code you're working so that I can recreate the problem you're having

Comment: https://thebusinessphone.com/ this is the link to the website I am working on, that has the problem with the left sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

```
#secondary {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 -97.5%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 122px;
        /*add this*/
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
}
```

In the line: top: 50px, 50px is height of navigation (menu)
Let me know if it works

Comment: No, it just disappears if I add these elements.

Comment: I forgot to use left: 0; can you put it into your code, if it doesn't work, tell me, I think you code get something wrong

Comment: Do you have codepen or virtual host that I can try to fix it for you?